# Eufemismos en la lengua coloquial

Tags: coloquialismos, eufemismos

Volviendo hoy del trabajo, oí al pasar algo así como:

> "Me importa un **joraca**." (Equivalente a "Me importa un carajo", o sea, "nada".)

Entonces advertí que ésa es una de la técnicas que tiene el español rioplatense para suavizar una palabra algo fuerte, como "carajo": la inversión de las sílabas.

Otro mecanismo muy usual por estos pagos consiste en utilizar una palabra parecida que contiene la palabra que podría considerarse agresiva o mal conceptuada. Así, en vez de decir "duro" a veces decimos "durazno", o en lugar de "lento", "lenteja", o en lugar de decir que algo vino de arriba (de alguna potestad superior, sin ningún esfuerzo propio), decimos que vino "de arribeño".

Pregunta 1) Creo que ambos mecanismos provienen del lunfardo porteño, cosa que me gustaría confirmar.

Pregunta 2) También querría preguntar a los participantes de este foro, tan variado en sus nacionalidades, qué eufemismos usan/usáis en sus/vuestras respectivas variedades del español, y si es posible el origen de los mismos.

Comment: Como pregunta, me parece interesante, pero el problema es que es un poco [off-topic](https://spanish.stackexchange.com/help/dont-ask). Preguntas por una lista de cosas y cada respuesta puede ser igual de válida que las demás. Lo único que se me ocurre para mantenerla es convertirla en Community Wiki y tener respuesta CW también donde cada usuario pueda aportar entradas de su región. Podemos convertirla en CW o si quieres puedes editar la pregunta para tratar de hacerla un poco más on-topic.

Comment: Soy consciente de que pueden ser válidas diversas respuestas, pero una pregunta no tiene necesariamente una sola respuesta, ¿no? Me imaginé a los usuarios - yo incluido - puntuando las distintas respuestas. Si te parece, conviértela en CW (y por favor dime cómo acceder, pues no tengo idea).

Comment: Ahí le di una vuelta de tuerca. Fíjate qué te parece... Lo dejo a tu criterio.

Comment: ¡Qué pregunta tan interesante! Me pareció muy ocurrente lo de _carajo_ -> _joraca_. Este "método" nunca lo he visto utilizar en España. Sin embargo, lo de _lento_ -> _lenteja_ y similares (_claro_ -> _clarinete_), sí.

Comment: @fedorqui Es un recurso llamado, con toda lógica, [_vesre_](https://es.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Vesre), era muy común en el viejo lunfardo porteño y aún sobrevive: _joraca_, _dolobu_, _yosapa_, _dolape_, etc. Una anécdota, que no puedo verificar, decía que Virulazo, un famoso bailarín de tango, trataba de enseñarle a una extranjera que no le entendía y, en un momento, molesto, le dijo: "¡la naerpi zurda, al tefrén!". Supongo que le habrá entendido aún menos.

Comment: The practice of moving part of the end of the word to the beginning is known for some reason in English as pig Latin so this is a much wider practice than one language in one part of its range.

Comment: Dejemos entonces la pregunta tal y como está y abramos una respuesta única, tipo Community Wiki para las aportaciones de eufemismos por regiones.

Comment: @mdewey Would you be so kind as to give us some examples of pig Latin?

Comment: I suspect examples would be off-topic here but fortunately https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Pig_Latin comes to the rescue.

Comment: Como ya es evidente por los comentarios y respuestas, no es un fenómeno exclusivo del lunfardo. En Colombia hacemos lo mismo solo que la inversion de sílabas es más por "mitades". Ej. carajo=jo-cara.

Comment: @DGaleano - Creo que vale la pena poner ese dato de Colombia en una respuesta parcial.

Answer (score 6):

**Con respecto a su primera pregunta:**

Como @JMVanPelt y otros han dicho, la palabra 'joraca' es un buen ejemplo del  *vesre,*  que es sólo una parte pequeña del fenómeno rioplatense del lunfardo. Si has oido  *zabeca (cabeza), lleca (calle),* o *jermu (mujer),*  sabes un poco más de este juego lingüístico.

Por otra parte, el Pig Latin de inglés no utiliza una técnica parecida.

En Francia, lo que se usan es el [verlan](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Verlan), que realmente proporciona una comparación mejor. Como el vesre, el verlan funciona por dividir palabras específicas en sus sílabas, e invirtiéndolas. El enlace describe que el nombre mismo  *verlan*  es una inversión del sonidos en el término francés  *l'envers,*  que significa invertir.

En Pig Latin, todo depende en si una palabra comienza con un consonante, o con una vocal:

- Si la palabra comienza con un consonante o grupo de consonantes, se mueven hasta el final, y tú añade el sonido '-ay'.  *Cat*  se convierte a  *atcay,*   *dog*  a *ogday,*  y  *pig*  a  *igpay.*
- Si la palabra comienza con una vocal, añade '-way', 'yay', o '-ay' al final.  *Argentina*  se convierte a  *Argentinaway*  o  *Argentinayay.*

Hay varias formas del Pig Latin, pero esos son las reglas básicas. Puedes ver que, como argot, no está firmemente enraizado en  *la reversión de las sílabas*  como el vesre o el verlan. Dicho esto, ciertamente tiene sus similitudes.

En mi opinion, es fascinante que diversos países y lenguas alrededor del mundo comparten esta línea común. Quizás los inmigrantes europeos de los principios del siglo XX ayudó a llevar estos manierismos a Argentina. Considera la influencia italiana, etc. Me parece que las clases bajas y la gente joven desempeñan un papel también; según [Oscar Conde](http://www.notimerica.com/cultura/noticia-oscar-conde-lunfardo-argot-nacional-argentina-20150321181250.html), miembro de la Academia Porteña del Lunfardo:

> El lunfardo... es un vocabulario de las clases populares, no una jerga delictiva... había pasado de ser el argot de las clases bajas a convertirse en un argot nacional.

De cualquier manera, los seres humanos siempre quieren una manera de divertir, y jugar con los idiomas no necesita baterías :)

Comment: ¡Qué respuesta tan fantástica! Bienvenido/a a [spanish.se] :)

Comment: @fedorqui ¡Mil gracias! Estoy emocionado de estar aquí :)

Comment: ¡Qué bien! Paséate por el [tour], [ask] y [answer] para ver un poco cómo funcionamos aquí. Esperamos con ganas tus siguientes respuestas o preguntas.

Answer (score 4):

### Lista de eufemismos

## Chile

- *Miércoles* y *[miércale](http://dle.rae.es/?id=PDmbWz9)*, interjecciones que reemplazan a "mierda".
- *[Pucha](http://dle.rae.es/?id=UYn3Zit)*, una mezcla de "puta" y "chucha", se usa para suavizar otras exclamaciones: *pucha qué rabia*.
- *La [contumelia](http://dle.rae.es/?id=AepiiCV)*, reemplaza a "la concha de su madre" cuando se habla de golpes. *Me saqué la contumelia patinando*.
- *Cocos* y *coquimbanos* por "testículos". (Coquimbo es una ciudad y coquimbano es el gentilicio).
- *Retamboriao*, *retutatutata*. No sé realmente de donde derivan ni qué reemplazan, pero son insultos suaves más o menos equivalentes a "estúpido". Si vas a soltar una palabrota horrible, te muerdes la lengua y lo cambias por "mejor cállate retamboriao".
- Una forma muy grosera de decirle al pene es "pichula", palabra de origen oscuro, probablemente indígena. Se suaviza con varios eufemismos como *pirula, pirulín* y *tula*.
- *Pechugas* (así, en plural) son cariñosamente las mamas.

## España

- *Gilipichis*, *gilitonto* y otras variedades de *gili-algo*, incluyendo *gili* sin más; *tontolaba* (con distintas grafías: b, v, etc.); *bobochorra*
- *Joer*, *jolín*, *jolines*, *jopé*, *jopelines*
- *Me la refanfinfla* en lugar de expresiones como "Me la suda" o "Me la sopla"
- *Cataplines*, en lugar de otras referencias malsonantes hacia los testículos
- *Donde la espalda cambia de nombre*, en lugar de *culo*
- [*Compañon*](http://lema.rae.es/drae2001/?val=compa%C3%B1%C3%B3n) y su plural, *compañones* por testículo(s).
- [*Panocha*](http://dle.rae.es/?id=RhpadY5): Órgano sexual tanto del varón como de la mujer (usado más en América lo segundo).
- [*Tal por cual*](https://dle.rae.es/?id=Yy91lUI) : hijo de puta (*C. Rica y El Salv.*)

Eufemismos usados en el pasado o en la literatura:

- *Quiñones*, en lugar de testículos. Por ejemplo:

  > Para asaltar torreones, cuatro Quiñones son pocos. ¡Hacen falta más Quiñones!
  > <sub>Pedro Muñoz Seca, *La venganza de Don Mendo*.</sub>

[**Wikipedia**](https://es.wikipedia.org/wiki/Eufemismo#Ejemplos_comunes) incluye ejemplos adicionales y una explicación de los diferentes tipos de eufemismos

Comment: @Luis, ¿en que parte de España se usa eso de quiñones? Nunca lo he oído.

Comment: @blonfu: He incluido una cita de Muñoz Seca. Además de Quiñones, he oido muchas otras palabras / apellidos con la misma rima (quintañones, coscollones....

Comment: @Luis, que estuviera en mayúscula me ha hecho pensar que tal vez era un nombre propio y efectivamente leyendo el poema completo se refiere a los hermanos Quiñones,  no a los testículos.

Comment: @blonfu: siempre he entendido que la primera vez se refiere a los hermanos, pero que "¡Hacen falta más Quiñones!" era un eufemismo por testiculos, haciendo un juego de palabras con el apellido. Y que eso se refleja en otras palabras acabadas en "-ones" usadas igualmente como eufemismo

Comment: Lo de "Miguelito" no es un eufemismo ya que no remplaza una palabra grosera o malsonante.

Comment: @Luis, es posible pero entonces sería algo único de esa obra en concreto

Comment: A falta de más ejemplos, estoy de acuerdo con @blonfu. Más bien parece que Muñoz Seca usó la similitud fonética, esperando que los espectadores de la obra captaran la referencia, pero no es un eufemismo de uso generalizado.

Comment: @blonfu - Yo también estaba dudando de esto, pero luego decidí que Miguelito sí funciona, porque lo se está cubriendo es el egoísmo.  La persona que dice, "Carmela hizo una cacerola especial para Miguelito," quiere jactarse sin dar la aparencia de estarse jactando.

Comment: @Gorpik - Mira también mi comentario por favor, a ver se les convenzo.

Comment: @aparente001 borré lo de Miguelito porque me parecía que no era un eufemismo pero puedes ponerlo otra vez si quieres. Y Gorpik no hablaba de eso  sino de lo de Quiñones.