# Diferencia entre "coloquialismo" y "vulgarismo", y su relación con "eufemismo"

Tags: coloquialismos, dle, terminología, eufemismos

Recientemente un usuario propuso eliminar de la respuesta comunitaria a [Eufemismos en la lengua coloquial](https://spanish.stackexchange.com/questions/21374/eufemismos-en-la-lengua-coloquial/21378#21378) la entrada para [*panocha*](http://dle.rae.es/?id=RhpadY5), argumentando que en el DLE está marcada como "**vulg.**" y por tanto no se puede considerar un eufemismo.

El DLE define "eufemismo" como:

> **[eufemismo](http://dle.rae.es/?id=H5kEJUG)**
>   Del lat. *euphemismus*, y este del gr. εὐφημισμός *euphēmismós*.
>
> 1. m. Manifestación suave o decorosa de ideas cuya recta y franca expresión sería dura o malsonante.

Y "vulgar" como:

> **[vulgar](http://dle.rae.es/?id=c5Ns9tE)**
>   Del lat. *vulgāris*.
>
> 1. adj. Perteneciente o relativo al vulgo.
>    2. adj. Dicho de una persona: Que pertenece al vulgo. Era u. t. c. s.
>    3. adj. Que es impropio de personas cultas o educadas.
>    4. adj. Común o general, por contraposición a especial o técnico.
>    5. adj. Que no tiene especialidad particular en su línea.
>    6. adj. Dicho de una lengua: Que se habla actualmente, por contraposición a las lenguas sabias.

De entrada, no me queda claro a cuál de estas acepciones se refiere la RAE cuando dice que una palabra es "vulgar". Podría ser la de "impropio de personas cultas o educadas", pero entonces no me cuadra con la definición de "vulgarismo" (el otro término usado por la RAE para referirse a estas palabras):

> **[vulgarismo](http://dle.rae.es/?id=c5QpjUZ)**
>   De *vulgar* e *-ismo*.
>
> 1. m. Dicho o frase especialmente usada por el vulgo.

La cuestión es que, en la respuesta arriba mencionada, sí que aparecen varias palabras y expresiones como [*pechuga*](http://dle.rae.es/?id=SGsYii2), [*jolín*](http://dle.rae.es/?id=MVzRpRb) o [*me la refanfinfla*](http://dle.rae.es/?id=Vc1rD9q) marcadas como "**coloq.**":

> **[coloquial](http://dle.rae.es/?id=9qTM1me)**
>
> 2. adj. Propio de una conversación informal y distendida. *Expresión, tono, estilo coloquial.*

Entonces, tenemos que un "vulgarismo" es una palabra o frase usada por el pueblo, mientras que un "coloquialismo" es una palabra o frase usada en una conversación informal.

¿Cuál es la diferencia?
¿Cuál es el criterio de la RAE para marcar una palabra como *vulgarismo* o *coloquialismo*? ¿Existen palabras con ambas marcas?
¿Es correcto interpretar que *vulgarismo* y *eufemismo* son excluyentes?

Comment: Si buscas en el [DIRAE](https://dirae.es) el término de búsqueda "vulg coloq" (sin las comillas) encuentras muchos resultados de palabras con ambas marcas. Por ejemplo: [furrusca](http://dle.rae.es/?id=IdeVZMf), "vulg. coloq. Col. Gresca, pelotera."

Comment: A la vista de la información que aportas aquí, me parece que tienes toda la razón y que yo eataba equivocado. Así pues, un vulgarismo puede ser un eufemismo.  ¡Cosas veredes!

Answer (score 8, accepted):

En este [tuit](https://twitter.com/raeinforma/status/413617822049517568) de la RAE se puede ver una conversación acerca de los vulgarismos:

> —¿Los vulgarismos se consideran faltas ortográficas? Como por ejemplo: asín.
>
> —No es una falta de ortografía, sino de corrección en la selección de la forma apropiada en el habla culta.
>
> —Entonces, en teoría, ¿puedo usarla en cualquier contexto sin que sea erróneo? Texto legal, memoria de un trabajo...
>
> —No, pues se trata de un vulgarismo, esto es, de una forma impropia del habla culta.

De acá tenemos una primera definición de vulgarismo: una forma impropia del habla culta.

En [Fundéu](https://www.fundeu.es/noticia/chispitas-de-lenguaje-respeto-a-vulgarismos-6563/)  encontramos una nota acerca de los vulgarismos y se puede deducir su relación con los coloquialismos:

> Los vulgarismos merecen respeto. Nuestro idioma, su estado actual, es una consecuencia de ellos. No dejan de ser una incomodidad para la gente culta, pero la historia demuestra que terminan por imponerse y, entonces, se transforman en palabras de uso común, coloquiales. Algunas llegan, incluso, a formar parte del léxico culto del idioma —como ejemplificaré más adelante—.

Entonces, de esto se podría decir que: el vulgarismo es un uso (quizá no muy extendido) impropio del habla culta, que podría, por la evolución del lenguaje, transformarse en un coloquialismo e incluso en palabra culta.

Más adelante, en la misma nota, se menciona un caso de un eufemismo que surgió a partir de un vulgarismo:

> Un caso más o menos reciente es la voz 'caray' derivada por eufemismo de 'carajo' (pene) —según José Cuervo, lingüista colombiano—. Hoy es parte del lenguaje coloquial, sin el menor asomo de vulgarismos.

Entonces, retomando y a modo de conclusión yo diría:

- Un *vulgarismo* es un uso impropio del habla culta. No implica necesariamente que la palabra en sí haga referencia a algo soez o "malsonante". En [Wikilengua](http://www.wikilengua.org/index.php/Vulgarismo) se define como: "... una expresión morfológica, fonética o sintáctica empleada en lugar de la palabra correcta y que no se considera parte de la llamada lengua culta." [Ej](https://gramatica.celeberrima.com/que-es-un-vulgarismo-y-67-ejemplos/):

  - a la mejor (a lo mejor);
  - alante (delante o adelante);
  - delen (denle), difierencia (diferencia);
- Un *coloquialismo* es usado en una conversación cotidiana. No se trata de un error o un uso impropio del idioma, pero tampoco sería lo usado en una conversación formal. [Ej:](http://www.ejemplode.com/60-que_significa/3085-ejemplo_de_coloquialismo.html)

  - ¡Qué tal! (Saludo.)
  - ¡Qué onda! (Saludo.)
  - ¡Metió la pata! (Cometió un error.)
- Un *eufemismo*, como se indica en la pregunta, suaviza una idea dura o malsonante. En un ejemplo ya se veía que incluso un vulgarismo podría transformarse en un eufemismo, pero no creo que estén relacionados entre ellos, o que tengan alguna exclusión mutua. [Ej:](https://es.wikipedia.org/wiki/Eufemismo)

  - poco agraciado (feo);
  - neutralizar, dar de baja, eliminar  (matar);
  - alimentos en mal estado (podridos)

Sobre el eufemismo se menciona también en [este documento](http://sedici.unlp.edu.ar/bitstream/handle/10915/49314/Documento_completo.pdf?) que:

> "... en el idioma corriente se recurre a expresiones de reemplazo para un término a fin de atenuar el impacto psicológico del mismo. El producto de este tipo de subterfugios se conoce como eufemismo o atenuación. Es una forma de suavizar o encubrir una expresión indeseable o desagradable"

Comment: Tu ultimo ejemplo me ha hecho pensar... ¿Realmente es un eufemismo llamar "centro de salud mental" a un "manicomio", o es simplemente el modo formal siendo "manicomio" mas vulgar?

Comment: @BrianH.Desde mi punto de vista, manicomio no es en sí un vulgarismo (y tampoco lo sugiere así el [DLE](http://dle.rae.es/?id=ODJb5UD) ). Lo digo porque en sí manicomio no parece una modificación de una palabra correcta en una incorrecta (haya->haiga), por ejemplo. Incluso su etimología es clara respecto a lo que significa ("De manía y el gr. κομεῖν komeîn 'cuidar'."). Me parece más bien que es una palabra con poco tacto y muy cruda y eso es lo que se quiere solucionar con el uso de la otra expresión.

Comment: Ahora, es cierto que en un artículo científico, por ejemplo, o en un congreso, probablemente nadie mencione la palabra "manicomio". ¿Quizá clasifique más entonces como un coloquialismo?

Comment: Mauricio, me pareció muy bien toda la respuesta, menos el último ejemplo; *manicomio* no es un buen ejemplo de *eufemismo* porque es un término anticuado y ofensivo.  Si tu hermano estuviera pasando por un periodo difícil y tuviera que internarse en un centro de salud mental, te gustaría que tu prima dijera, "Ah, pues, está en el manicomio"?  Me imagino que no; te propongo que quites ese ejemplo.

Comment: @aparente001 Lo elimino para evitar generar un mal ambiente. Sigo pensando, sin embargo, que era un ejemplo válido. De acuerdo que es una palabra ofensiva y que suena mal, Por la sensibilidad que puede generar es precisamente que se usan eufemismos en su lugar. En el [documento](http://sedici.unlp.edu.ar/bitstream/handle/10915/49314/Documento_completo.pdf)que adjunté como actualización de la respuesta se pueden ver varios ejemplos de eufemismos relacionados con esa palabra ( y otras más).

Comment: Gracias.  Me pregunto hasta dónde se llegaría con esa lógica.  ¿Se podría decir que "gay" es un eufemismo para "maricón"?  A mi aviso, no.  Hay palabras que hoy día se reconocen como lenguaje despectivo, que anteriormente se usaban comúnmente (pero que sin embargo eran ofensivas para algunas personas).  Para mí, esas situaciones no caen dentro de lo que es un eufemismo.  "Hacer del dos" es un eufemismo, pero las frases más explícitas que quedan remplazadas *no ofenden a ningún sector especial de la población*.

Comment: Conclusión: creo que *eufemismo* no es un sinónimo exacto y perfecto para "lenguaje respetuoso".